# cURL and fopen slow in browser, quick via command line

Tags: php, apache, curl, fopen

I have an issue where I am trying to connect to a remote server to retrieve data. There are 2 methods. One is using fopen and the other is using cURL. Both of them are painfully slow in the browser, to a point where it loads and nothing happens. It will just return a "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Chrome.

However, when I run the same script via command line (Apache, Ubuntu), it works rapidly. Are there any obvious reasons why this may be?

This data fetch method works fine on other servers and in command line as I said, but not in the browser for this server. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to connect with ip address? I suspect DNS name-resolution.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is a chrome error. It has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give it a go now...

Comment: OK - @LajosVeres I have changed the nameserver in resolv.conf to Google's 8.8.8.8 and it's still not working

Comment: Are the curl/fopen connection faster with using ip address instead of host name calling the php from chrome?

Comment: Hi @LajosVeres - thanks again for the help. I've just discovered that it was an issue with fastCGI settings.