# PHP Curl/file_get_contents inconsistent response time in Chrome

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, curl, fiddler

I'm on Windows 7 (using a VirtualBox VM) to do some development. I have PHP/5.5.13, Apache 2.4.9, Chrome 35.0.1916.153. I'm seeing some very inconsistent behavior when I run the following code :

**index2.php**

```
<?php
echo "Load time before 'file_get_contents': ".(microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'])."<br/>\r\n";
echo file_get_contents('http://custom.local/index3.php');
echo "Load time after 'file_get_contents': ".(microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'])."<br/>\r\n";
exit;
?>
```

**index3.php**

```
<?php
echo "Load time inside 'index3.php': ".(microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'])."<br/>\r\n";
exit;
?>
```

Here is the results in Chrome (I get consistent response time between 8 and 28 seconds after curl_exec). Response time fluctuates a lot as well:

```
Load time before 'file_get_contents': 0.002000093460083
Load time inside 'index3.php': 0.0026569366455078
Load time after 'file_get_contents': 15.411452054977
```

Comment: One thing I may add, I just uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome and got the same results. I just reinstalled Fiddler, and clearly when Fiddler is running, I get the normal behavior (below 10 ms response time). Could this be a bug with Chrome's proxy settings - misbehaving with Fiddler?

Comment: Don't add comments - edit the question; timestamps would actually be more useful as it'd clarify where the delay occurs. However: what you know atm is that the curl  request is processed in 0.002s. that means the request was stalled, at the webserver, for 26.71s before it was passed to php. One typical cause is hitting the max-clients the webserver can handle - check your webserver logs for relevant messages.

Comment: Just added an update - thanks for the suggestion but unless I didn't tweak the right settings it's not making any difference. I thought of this one as well before... But since this is the only test running on this server I don't see how it could use all threads. Nothing in logs either.

Comment: Eliminating a cause is still progress, but since it looks like a network problem of some sort and not code related it may well be considered off-topic for SO. Alternatively fiddler must have some kind of inspection information to review.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what the issue is... I saw an other similar thread but no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319677/curl-and-fopen-slow-in-browser-quick-via-command-line

Comment: Oh other precision, this should not be a network issue since my VM runs locally.

Comment: I say network issue because the problem occurs inbetween index2.php initiating a curl request and index3.php starting to process anything.  Don't fall into the trap of assuming it's not x because `<turns out not relevant>` - base understanding on observed results. E.g. does the problem go away after uninstalling fiddler? then that is part of the problem.

Comment: Just added more edits... it must be related to network somehow but I suspect a bug between Fiddler and Chrome. I think I will open a ticket with them unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after all it was an Apache issue.

Chrome's advanced options "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" would use more threads than provisioned by the default Apache config (Windows 2.4.9 Windows build).

The fix is simple in httpd.conf :

`AcceptFilter http none`

More details here:

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=28142#28142